# Laravel withErrors 5.4.36 is empty within view

Tags: php, laravel

Strange issue here! My return code within the controller is as follows:

```
return back()->withErrors([ 'not_updated' => 'Unable to update record or no changes made' ]);
```

And then I display the errors within blade:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <article class="message is-danger">
        <div class="message-body">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
@endif
```

However this doesn't appear to be working at all, `$errors` is empty for some reason, however this works fine from another controller!

This is the method where this works, I have included the **use** classes.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pages;
use App\PlannerStatus;
use App\SubPages;
use App\VehicleMake;
use App\Website;
use App\WebsiteRedirects;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;

class RedirectsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request, Website $website)
    {

        $error = [ 'test' => 'test error' ];

        if (!empty($error)) {
            return back()->withErrors($error)->withInput();
        }


        return back();

    }
}
```

And this is the controller where this does **NOT** work, as you can see they are the same, more or less!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ResultsText;
use App\VehicleMake;
use App\VehicleModel;
use App\VehicleType;
use App\SearchPath;
use App\Website;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Redirect;

class ResultsTextController extends Controller
{

    public function update(Website $website, ResultsText $resultsText, Request $request)
    {

        $data = request()->except(['_token','id']);

        $result = ResultsText::where('id', $resultsText->id)->update($data);

        if (!$result) {
            return back()->withErrors([ 'not_updated' => 'Unable to update record or no changes made' ]);
        }

        return Redirect::action('ResultsTextController@index', $website);

    }


}
```

Also here are my **Routes**, just so you can see they are pretty much identical:

```
Route::prefix('/redirects')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'RedirectsController@index')->middleware('SettingStatus:redirect');
    Route::patch('/update', 'RedirectsController@update');
});

Route::prefix('/results-text')->group(function () {
    Route::post('{resultsText}/update', 'ResultsTextController@update');
});
```

Comment: are you sure you are redirecting to the right place?

Comment: Yep, i'm just going back to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your blade try this

```
@if ($errors->any())
<article class="message is-danger">
    <div class="message-body">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easily overlooked in your question. The problem is not what it seems. You will probably find it funny why it doesn't work.

Replace

```
return back()->withErrors([ 'not_updated' => 'Unable to update record or no changes made' ]);
```

with

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([ 'not_updated' => 'Unable to update record or no changes made' ]);
```